# @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) empieza desde 0, habiendo 3 registros iniciales en la db

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

tengo un archivo data.sql

```
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (id, name) VALUES (1, 'shoes');
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (id, name) VALUES (2, 'books');
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (id, name) VALUES (3, 'electronics');

INSERT INTO tbl_products (id, name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES (1, 'adidas Cloudfoam Ultimate','Walk in the air in the black / black CLOUDFOAM ULTIMATE running shoe from ADIDAS',5,178.89,'CREATED','2018-09-05',1);

INSERT INTO tbl_products (id, name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES (2, 'under armour Men ''s Micro G Assert – 7','under armour Men ''Lightweight mesh upper delivers complete breathability . Durable leather overlays for stability ',4,12.5,'CREATED','2018-09-05',1);


INSERT INTO tbl_products (id, name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES (3, 'Spring Boot in Action','under armour Men '' Craig Walls is a software developer at Pivotal and is the author of Spring in Action',12,40.06,'CREATED','2018-09-05',2);
```

mis entidades son:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_categories")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_products")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Double stock;
    private Double price;
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "create_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createAt;
    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
    
}
```

el problema es que al ingresar un nuevo producto, me salta el error de repeticion de llave primaria.

me di cuenta que a los 3 primeros intentos sale ese error, entra en conflicto con el id del registro 1, luego con el 2, luego con el 3,
pero al cuarto ya me deja registrar. creo que el problema es que identiti esta empezando desde el 1, y en cada intento va subiendo hasta llegar al 4.
como puedo hacer para resolver este error.
dejo el archivo de configuracion:

```
#Application Configuration
server:
  port: 8091

# To See H2 Console in Browser:
# http://localhost:8091/h2-console
# Enabling H2 Console
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  # ===============================
  # DB
  # ===============================
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:productDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

  # ===============================
  # JPA / HIBERNATE
  # ===============================
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: false
        format_sql: false
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

talves sea algo con la configuracion de h2 o nose. pueden ayudarme.

Comment: Por favor, pon todo el código como texto, no uses imágenes. No puedo copiar y pegar líneas de código a la respuesta desde tus imágenes. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: ok ya lo reforme. gracias por la recomendacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro al 100% porque no puedo probarlo ahora mismo, pero creo que lo que te pasa es lo siguiente:

- Por un lado tienes la configuración

```yaml
jpa:
    ...
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Lo que indica a la aplicación que elimine todo el esquema al terminar la ejecución y lo cree de nuevo.

- Por otro lado usas para la generación de identificadores la estrategia IDENTITY:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

Esto significa que JPA delega en la base de datos la creación de un valor auto-incrementado secuencial, que por defecto empezará en 1.

- Pero cuando insertas manualmente, indicas explícitamente el ID:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (id, name) VALUES (1, 'shoes');
```

Por lo que la secuencia que se usa para generar el ID no es llamada, lo que hace que se mantenga con el valor inicial, que es 1.

- Esto hace que cuando tu aplicación intente insertar algo nuevo, usando algo similar a

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (name) VALUES ('cars');
```

tu base de datos intente usar la secuencia generada junto con la tabla. Pero puesto que esa secuencia no ha sido actualizada, intentará usar el valor 1. La inserción fallará, pero la secuencia ya ha sido incrementada, por lo que en la siguiente llamada valdrá 2. Y seguirá fallando hasta que la secuencia llegue a un valor que no está ya siendo usado como ID.

#### Solución

Eliminar el ID de tus inserciones manuales y dejar que sea la propia base de datos la que genere el valor. Si quieres asegurarte de que los productos apuntan a la categoría correcta, quizá necesitas incluir un select en cada insert para obtener la categoría por el nombre:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (name) VALUES ('shoes');
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (name) VALUES ('books');
INSERT INTO tbl_categories (name) VALUES ('electronics');

INSERT INTO tbl_products (name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES ('adidas Cloudfoam Ultimate','Walk in the air in the black / black CLOUDFOAM ULTIMATE running shoe from ADIDAS',5,178.89,'CREATED','2018-09-05',1);

INSERT INTO tbl_products (name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES ('under armour Men ''s Micro G Assert – 7','under armour Men ''Lightweight mesh upper delivers complete breathability . Durable leather overlays for stability ',4,12.5,'CREATED','2018-09-05',1);


INSERT INTO tbl_products (name, description, stock,price,status, create_at,category_id)
VALUES ('Spring Boot in Action','under armour Men '' Craig Walls is a software developer at Pivotal and is the author of Spring in Action',12,40.06,'CREATED','2018-09-05',2);
```

Comment: si gracias, esa era la solucion.